# SQL Select Convert State Name To Abbreviation

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

In a SQL select statement, how to convert a full state name to state abbreviation (e.g. `New York` to `NY`)? I'd like to do this without joins if possible. What would the `regexp_replace` look like?

`select regexp_replace(table.state, 'New York', 'NY', 'g') as state`
Can this approach be done en mass for all states?

For reference list of states names and abbreviations: https://gist.github.com/esfand/9443427.

Comment: Load the abbreviations into a table and use `JOIN`.  Why would you NOT want to use `JOIN`?

Comment: I cannot imagine a regex that could return NY from New York, CT from Connecticut, CA from California, etc. Use a lookup  table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff @Andrew: I'm can use `select regexp_replace(table.state, 'New York', 'NY', 'g') as state` wondering if it's possible to do a regex replace for each state name to abbreviation.

Comment: in that case you have to write 50 case statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PostgreSQL you can use JSON

```
select '{"Alabama": "AL", "Alaska": "AK"}'::json->'Alabama'
```

You can also use a column reference instead of a string literal

```
select 
'{"Alabama": "AL", "Alaska": "AK"}'::json->example.state 
from 
(values ('Alabama')) example(state)
```

Comment: I assume it is about PostgreSQL because your question has the corresponding tag.

Comment: Upvoted for thinking outside the box, but it doesn't do a replace on a selected column. e.g. I can't use it on `select state_name`

Comment: @Steve I have added an example with a column reference.

Comment: Perfect, that answers my question exactly. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

Here it is in raw WHEN/THEN form if needed, along with Canadian provinces:

```
CASE "YOUR COLUMN CONTAINING FULL STATE NAMES"
WHEN 'Alabama' THEN 'AL' 
WHEN 'Alaska' THEN 'AK' 
WHEN 'Arizona' THEN 'AZ' 
WHEN 'Arkansas' THEN 'AR' 
WHEN 'California' THEN 'CA' 
WHEN 'Colorado' THEN 'CO' 
WHEN 'Connecticut' THEN 'CT' 
WHEN 'Delaware' THEN 'DE' 
WHEN 'District of Columbia' THEN 'DC' 
WHEN 'Florida' THEN 'FL' 
WHEN 'Georgia' THEN 'GA' 
WHEN 'Hawaii' THEN 'HI' 
WHEN 'Idaho' THEN 'ID' 
WHEN 'Illinois' THEN 'IL' 
WHEN 'Indiana' THEN 'IN' 
WHEN 'Iowa' THEN 'IA' 
WHEN 'Kansas' THEN 'KS' 
WHEN 'Kentucky' THEN 'KY' 
WHEN 'Louisiana' THEN 'LA' 
WHEN 'Maine' THEN 'ME' 
WHEN 'Maryland' THEN 'MD' 
WHEN 'Massachusetts' THEN 'MA' 
WHEN 'Michigan' THEN 'MI' 
WHEN 'Minnesota' THEN 'MN' 
WHEN 'Mississippi' THEN 'MS' 
WHEN 'Missouri' THEN 'MO' 
WHEN 'Montana' THEN 'MT' 
WHEN 'Nebraska' THEN 'NE' 
WHEN 'Nevada' THEN 'NV' 
WHEN 'New Hampshire' THEN 'NH' 
WHEN 'New Jersey' THEN 'NJ' 
WHEN 'New Mexico' THEN 'NM' 
WHEN 'New York' THEN 'NY' 
WHEN 'North Carolina' THEN 'NC' 
WHEN 'North Dakota' THEN 'ND' 
WHEN 'Ohio' THEN 'OH' 
WHEN 'Oklahoma' THEN 'OK' 
WHEN 'Oregon' THEN 'OR' 
WHEN 'Pennsylvania' THEN 'PA' 
WHEN 'Rhode Island' THEN 'RI' 
WHEN 'South Carolina' THEN 'SC' 
WHEN 'South Dakota' THEN 'SD' 
WHEN 'Tennessee' THEN 'TN' 
WHEN 'Texas' THEN 'TX' 
WHEN 'Utah' THEN 'UT' 
WHEN 'Vermont' THEN 'VT' 
WHEN 'Virginia' THEN 'VA' 
WHEN 'Washington' THEN 'WA' 
WHEN 'West Virginia' THEN 'WV' 
WHEN 'Wisconsin' THEN 'WI' 
WHEN 'Wyoming' THEN 'WY' 
WHEN 'Alberta' THEN 'AB' 
WHEN 'British Columbia' THEN 'BC' 
WHEN 'Manitoba' THEN 'MB' 
WHEN 'New Brunswick' THEN 'NB' 
WHEN 'Newfoundland and Labrador' THEN 'NL' 
WHEN 'Northwest Territories' THEN 'NT' 
WHEN 'Nova Scotia' THEN 'NS' 
WHEN 'Nunavut' THEN 'NU' 
WHEN 'Ontario' THEN 'ON' 
WHEN 'Prince Edward Island' THEN 'PE' 
WHEN 'Quebec' THEN 'QC' 
WHEN 'Saskatchewan' THEN 'SK' 
WHEN 'Yukon Territory' THEN 'YT' 
    ELSE NULL
END
```

Comment: You're a real hero

Answer (score 1):

As comments suggested that a join is needed. Below is what I ended up doing. Let me know if there is a better way.

```
with states(name, abbr) as (
    select
    *
    from
    (values ('Alabama', 'AL'),
       ('Alaska', 'AK'),
       ('Arizona', 'AZ'),
       ('Arkansas', 'AR'),
       ('California', 'CA'),
       ('Colorado', 'CO'),
       ('Connecticut', 'CT'),
       ('Delaware', 'DE'),
       ('District of Columbia', 'DC'),
       ('Florida', 'FL'),
       ('Georgia', 'GA'),
       ('Hawaii', 'HI'),
       ('Idaho', 'ID'),
       ('Illinois', 'IL'),
       ('Indiana', 'IN'),
       ('Iowa', 'IA'),
       ('Kansas', 'KS'),
       ('Kentucky', 'KY'),
       ('Louisiana', 'LA'),
       ('Maine', 'ME'),
       ('Maryland', 'MD'),
       ('Massachusetts', 'MA'),
       ('Michigan', 'MI'),
       ('Minnesota', 'MN'),
       ('Mississippi', 'MS'),
       ('Missouri', 'MO'),
       ('Montana', 'MT'),
       ('Nebraska', 'NE'),
       ('Nevada', 'NV'),
       ('New Hampshire', 'NH'),
       ('New Jersey', 'NJ'),
       ('New Mexico', 'NM'),
       ('New York', 'NY'),
       ('North Carolina', 'NC'),
       ('North Dakota', 'ND'),
       ('Ohio', 'OH'),
       ('Oklahoma', 'OK'),
       ('Oregon', 'OR'),
       ('Pennsylvania', 'PA'),
       ('Rhode Island', 'RI'),
       ('South Carolina', 'SC'),
       ('South Dakota', 'SD'),
       ('Tennessee', 'TN'),
       ('Texas', 'TX'),
       ('Utah', 'UT'),
       ('Vermont', 'VT'),
       ('Virginia', 'VA'),
       ('Washington', 'WA'),
       ('West Virginia', 'WV'),
       ('Wisconsin', 'WI'),
       ('Wyoming', 'WY')) as state
)
```

And `select (select states.abbr from states where name = state_name)`